# Slideout page using javascript?

Tags: javascript

How do you create your own slideout page using javascript?

see http://support.tweetboard.com/home/#installation
click on "tweets"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a very simple solution using jQuery's `animate` method for the meat. (Working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rFbTZ/) and code below.)

**HTML**

You need three basic elements: a container (`#slideout`), its contents (`#slideout_contents`), and a toggle button (`#slideout_toggle`).

```
<body>
<div>Page contents. Page contents. Page contents. Page contents. Page contents. Page contents. Page contents. Page contents. Page contents. Page contents. Page contents. Page contents. Page contents. Page contents. Page contents. Page contents. Page contents.</div>
<div id="slideout">
    <div id="slideout_contents">
        <a id="slideout_toggle">Open</a>
        <h1>Header</h1>
        <p>Some text.</p>
        <p>Some text.</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>​
```

**CSS**

You need to position it absolutely so it hugs the left edge of the screen.

```
body {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
#slideout, #slideout_contents, #slideout_toggle {
    background: #000; /* to see it on a blank page */
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
}
#slideout_contents {
    left: -100px; /* adjust these */
    width: 100px;
    height: 300px;
}
#slideout_toggle {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    top: 50%;
    left: 100px;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}​
```

**JavaScript (jQuery)**

jQuery's `animate` method takes care of the rest.

```
$('#slideout_toggle').toggle(function(){
    $(this).html('Close');
    $('#slideout_contents').animate({'left': '0px'});
},function(){
    $(this).html('Open');
    $('#slideout_contents').animate({'left': '-100px'});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Any number of sites can show you how to do this. Here's one.

http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/index.html?whichScript=show_hide_content_slide